# Cordova splashscreen is restricted to a small circle with Cordova 11.0 and Android 12 API?

Tags: android, cordova, android-splashscreen

I'm doing the migration from Cordova 10.x to 11.x, and followed this [article](https://ionic.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/7891143965975-Migrating-to-Cordova-Android-11). On the former versions, user must provide the full images for all resolutions and define then using the `<splash>` tag; now, there's no `<splash>` tag anymore, but only one image.

The result is that the *splashscreen is smaller and restricted to a circle*, with radius of 1/3 of the width of the device.

The provided image has no borders, and my config.xml is as follow:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget
  ...
  <platform name="android">
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="32" />
    <preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" value="splash.png" />
    <preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenBackground" value="#FFFFFF" />
  ...
```

When I send small images, they are placed inside this circle. But bigger images are cropped.

Is it a desirable behavior? If yes, can I customize this size? I coudn't be able to found any way to define it's size at [Cordova Docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/core/features/splashscreen/index.html).

Here goes two printscreens from my mobile device:

Image of [Cordova 10 version (desired)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7iRU.png)

Image of [Cordova 11 version (cropped into a circle)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAvS5.png)

Any ideas ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen#splash_screen_dimensions) for sizes.
More info about this [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/pull/1441)

Comment: Hi @Eric, I have go through the link, but cant see any clue to increase the display size, is there any config I can change in config.xml to increase the size to larger?

Comment: hi @Eric, do u means increase the size of the image?

Comment: You can't increase the size. It's either 240p with color background or 288p with transparent background. The size of the circle in the image is also important. Edited for typo.

Comment: last time I am using full image to display the splashscreen in full screen. any other plugin I can use to replace this?

Comment: I don't think so...